# Retrieve DNS messages for custom MTA in ECM

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

Sitecore 6.6, Update 4 (rev 130214) with ECM 2.0 (rev 130123)

I've got a Sitecore installation where we're using a custom MTA.  I've configured the `Delivery Status Notifications` section in the Email Campaign Manager root to include my `Return Address` POP3 information.

The custom MTA is sending the emails and my POP3 account is receiving the DNS bounce emails.

I can't get this information back into ECM.  I've checked the `Checked Bounced Messages` task for ECM and while it's still configured to do the daily check, I've manually run it a number of times to no avail.

Any clues to why ECM wouldn't be able to pull in this information?

Thanks!

Comment: Craig, did you get anywhere with this? Did the below answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Sitecore support and through some decompiling and adding additional logging of the ECM code, we have determined that the problem is that the custom MTA was stripping out the original headers that contained the references to the Sitecore campaignID.

When the campaignID headers are present, ECM works great and has no problem pulling the bounce messages back into Sitecore.

Comment: Finally you got a solution to your issue. Good stuff!

Comment: I am also trying the same but can you please elaborate on how did you manage to put in the campaignID int he header.

Comment: @Selwyn: The campaignID is placed into the header of the outgoing ECM by default.  The problem with this particular client's setup was that their custom MTA software was stripping out all the additional headers that Sitecore was adding.  We had to configure the MTA to not strip out the headers.  Once that was corrected, things started working again.

Answer (score 4):

- Check your architecture setup as ECM will not automatically receive
  the DNS bouce emails count, as it is not using SAC because you are
  using a Custom MTA. Have a look at the below image.
- Since you are using Custom MTA, make sure you have the Delivery Status Notifications Settings configured properly. Especially the **Notification Gathering**, because guide says:

> Whether or not to collect delivery status notifications from the e
>   mail box used by the module for sending messages. If this check box is
>   cleared, the rest of the section is ignored.
>
> If this check box is selected, but other fields of this section are
>   empty, these fields will be inherited from the manager root.

- Make sure the below two steps are followed. Read [ECM Admin & Dev Guide](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/ecm/131/ecm_administrator_and_developer_guide_131-a4.pdf)

  - **The MTA server sends the DSN messages to the corporate email address.** The SMTP server sends the DSN messages to the address
    specified in the Return Address field. Usually this address is hosted
    on a corporate e-mail server.
  - **The ECM module connects to the e-mail server and gets the DSN messages for further analysis.** The POP3 protocol is used for this
    connection. For more information about collecting the DSN messages,
    see section Collecting Delivery Status Notifications.
- Lastly check the subscriber's profile for UndeliveredCount property for
  soft bounces and also the manager root item's Undelivered Max
  setting, which should give you soft bounces (or maximum value of
  UndeliveredCount property) per subscriber.

Let us know how you get along and if the above was useful.

[image]

Comment: +1 for your thorough answer, but unfortunately, I had everything configured as you have suggested.  I've reached out to Sitecore to see if they can provide any additional help.  Thanks!